# How to get libCEC for Python (PyCharm on Windows)?

Tags: python, pycharm, libraries, hdmi-cec

I am unfortunately an absolute beginner in programming.

First of all, I'm programming with the PyCharm IDE on a Windows computer, but the script will later run on a RaspberryPi.

I want to turn on my TV with a Python script via HDMI-CEC and I came across libcec.
However, I can't figure out the setup instructions for Windows.
https://github.com/trainman419/python-cec

Can anyone give me a step by step guide on what exactly I need to do to use the CEC commands in Python?

Or should I program with PyCharm directly on the RaspberryPi? This one is way too slow for this task in my opinion. Then I could install the CEC library very easily.

Thanks for your help.